# I am getting this error when i trying to set up Irvine lib for coding assembly in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, irvine32

First, I'm doing this step

[image]

But when i click and do next step like tutorial

Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies: user32.lib, Irvine32.lib (the tutorials missed the user32.lib but it is in sample project

my setting in this

[image]

not this

[image]

I can not understand where the error came from

please tell me how to fix it. I tried my best already

Comment: I think this was changed between versions of VS. In 2019 you would see the list, in 2022 you see the macros that will resolve to the list. When adding the dependencies, click the macro button and search to see what the macro will resovle to.

Answer (score 2):

This was changed between version. In 2019 you could see the list. In 2022 you see the macros that group this list into a macro.

You can see the expanded list in the `Additional Dependencies` window via the `Macros>>` button.

[image]

You could also go to the "Command Line" option and see expanded list there. That the final command that will get executed.